# Reading private variable of mapping(address => uint256) using getStorageAt

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin, ethers.js, openzeppelin-contracts

I'm trying to access a private variable in my contract using `getStorageAt()`.

OpenZepplin's PostDeliveryCrowdsale has the following (taken as-is):

```
contract PostDeliveryCrowdsale is TimedCrowdsale {
    using SafeMath for uint256;

    mapping(address => uint256) private _balances;   <--- I want to access this variable
```

I want to know the balance of a particular address in that variable. I figured instead of trying to count the slots, which may be difficult due to my crowdsale inheriting from many other OZ crowdsale contract, why not just iterate and find it:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
 
    const crowdsale = '0xa6297869D1300593be81589154C2a77c9b4D3f4e'; //crowdsale deployed on rinkeby
    const beneficiary = '0x5F53470Dd888A5AFfD3B41c1B4aEAC84C7ea0d61'; //buyer who successfully purchased tokens
 
    const index = (new utils.BigNumber(i)).toHexString();

    const newKeyPreimage = utils.concat([
      utils.hexZeroPad(beneficiary, 32),
      utils.hexZeroPad(index, 32),
    ]);

    const compositeKey = utils.keccak256(newKeyPreimage);


    const data = await this.web3.eth.getStorageAt(crowdsale, compositeKey);
    const decimal = this.web3.utils.toDecimal(data);
    console.log(`[${i}]: ${data}  toDecimal(): ${decimal}`)

}
```

But all I get are empty slots when using compositeKey

Code was taken from [here](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/1079) which seemed to work for the other guy.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: not an efficient method. a more efficient method would modify `ethclient` module of Geth and add a Call to return al the variables of a contract using this function: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/f0b1bddac41a31ff5b86c3d934acd19016aeb1d1/core/state/statedb.go#L616 , this way you will be able to get all variables of a contract via RPC API

Comment: @Nulik Just a question, doesn't the eth consensus check for client integrity? before synchronizing with the network ?

Comment: @KakiMasterOfTime the consensus only checks block headers and bodies, if we speak about `ethash` consensus, which is currently on the main net

Comment: Im not intending to iterate all the slots every time. Im doing this just to determine where the index is. After that I may hardcode it and add a unit test. There is already a public function balanceOf that returns the value I need. But Im still wondering why this method doesnt work, efficient or not.

Answer (score 1):

The storage of a mapping in solidity is the result of `keccak256(key, slot)`. Once you have that, you need to get the result of the storage, and then decode it to `uint`.

The answer of your question is the following:

```
const storageIndex = 0; //your mapping is at index 0
const key = "0x...." //the key for the mapping that you wish to access

const storage = web3.utils.soliditySha3({type:"address", value:key}, {type:"uint", value:0});
```

The result of storage will be the number you need in hex, just decode it.